Possible to extend the ReadonlyArray/ReadonlySet/ReadonlyMap in TypeScript?
Since the ReadonlyArray and like are the interfaces, they could not be extended by extend keyword:
export class ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> extends ReadonlyArray<ElementType> {
 // ...
}


TS2689: Cannot extend an interface ReadonlyArray. Did you mean implements?

We can write:
export class ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> extends Array<ElementType> implements ReadonlyArray<ElementType> {
  // ...
}

but actually implements ReadonlyArray<ElementType> gives nothing and all methods of mutable Array will be available that is unacceptable.
Well, what else possible?
Maybe some manipulations with types declaration or casting?
The below code is invalid but I suppose it will be something like this:
class ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> extends Array<ElementType> {
  // ...
}


// [ INVALID CODE ]
export default ReadonlyRowVector as unknown as ReadonlyArray<ElementType>;


TS2304: Cannot find name ElementType

What's new ReadonlyRowVector gives in addition to ReadonlyArray? Some new properties or methods?
I am planning to add some properties and methods to ReadonlyRowVector, but even it will be same with ReadonlyArray, it has the value because of providing the validation. From the viewpoint of the linear algebra, there are many limitations on the operations with vectors and matrices, so the checks like instance of ReadonlyRowVector or instance of ReadonlyColumnVector will required.
But, if you want to see the new properties or methods now, currently I am thinking the adding of fromArray static method and getElementAt__numerationFrom1 instance method:
import {
  isNaturalNumber,
  Logger,
  InvalidParameterValueError,
  isNumber
} from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


export default class ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> extends Array<ElementType> implements ReadonlyArray<ElementType> {

  public static fromArray<ElementType>(array: ReadonlyArray<ElementType>): ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> {
    return new ReadonlyRowVector(...array);
  }


  public constructor(...elements: ReadonlyArray<ElementType>) {
    super(...elements);
  }


  public getElementAt__numerationFrom1(targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1: number): ElementType {

    if (!isNaturalNumber(targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1)) {
      Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
        errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
          parameterNumber: 1,
          parameterName: "targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1",
          messageSpecificPart: [
            "Target element number must be the natural number ",
            ...isNumber(targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1) ?
                `while has value ${ targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1 } which is not the natural number.` :
                `while has type "${ typeof targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1 }".`
          ].join(" ")

        }),
        title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
        occurrenceLocation: "RowVector.getElementAt__numerationFrom1(targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1)"
      });
    }


    if (targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1 > this.length) {
      Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
        errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
          parameterNumber: 1,
          parameterName: "targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1",
          messageSpecificPart:
              `Element number ${ targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1 } (numeration from 1) requested while target ` +
              `RowVector has ${ this.length } elements.`

        }),
        title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
        occurrenceLocation: "RowVector.getElementAt__numerationFrom1(targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1)"
      });
    }

    return this[targetElementNumber__numerationFrom1 - 1];

  }


}


"Since the ReadonlyArray and like are the interfaces, they could not be extended by extend keyword" interfaces can extend interfaces. You can't extend an interface with a class because that doesn't make sense. Playground Link

What are you trying to achieve? What does your ReadonlyRowVector implementation do and how is it different from Array?

Could you please [edit] to put something inside ReadonlyRowVector (like a constructor method and some methods or props that make it differ from Array)?  This will help us show how to do it. Is it unacceptable that the mutable methods exist at runtime? If so then you're going to have to implement your whole class from scratch because Array has those methods. Or is it just unacceptable that they're accessible in the type? If so then you could do something like this which is a subclass of Array at runtime but only exposes the readonly parts to TS users.

@Bergi I am planning to add some properties and methods to ReadonlyRowVector, but even it will be same with ReadonlyArray, it has the value because of providing the validation. From the viewpoint of the linear algebra, there are many limitations on the operations with vectors and matrices, so the checks like instance of ReadonlyRowVector or instance of ReadonlyColumnVector will required.

@jcalz O'K, I have added. Maybe you will say now: "You don't need to create the ReadonlyRowVector only for these new methods, use the standard ReadonlyArray", but please note that currently the providing of x instanceof ReadonlyRowVector check is important rather than the adding of new properties and methods.

Mostly I want to see a [mre] here I can copy and paste into my own IDE to test my suggestions. So the version above with third-party imports means I can't easily test the functionality, although I can at least grab the types. So, if you look at this playground link you can see how I'd do this. The actual runtime class is mutable (and I've named it just RowVector) but you can expose ReadonlyRowVector as a constructor and a type that doesn't expose any mutable methods. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thank you for the comment. I have removed the third-party dependencies from the playgroud. Looks like work fine. Unfortunately, I can't 100% accept is because of usage of any type and as, but if you have not time to improve your solution, I'll accept it as hint with gratitude.

Do you mean you can't accept the Stack Overflow answer I'd write? Because it uses a type assertion (even though the question mentions possibly using "casting")? That's really out of scope for the question as asked, and still, the code here is not a [mre] as it depends on some external imported libraries. I am confused. Here, I spent thirty more seconds on it and came up with this version. Whether or not that's acceptable to your actual code base, it seems outside the scope of what should be acceptable for future readers of this question. How should we proceed here?

@jcalz "Do you mean you can't accept ..." - I mean your answer in comment. "even though the question mentions possibly using "casting" - yes, you are right. "and still, the code here is not" - I am sorry about this, but I have created the version without imports. "Here, I spent thirty more" - thank you very much for your time. I'll report once decide the final solution for my case.

Is there a reason you have --noUncheckedIndexedAccess being true there? Is it just because my original playground link had that? If so then that's the issue and you can fix it by turning it off, or having TS actually check whether the array element exists at runtime. Neither one really has much to do with your question, though.

The ReadonlyArray is an interface, not a class. When you declare an object as a ReadonlyArray, it is still a standard Array. However, the ReadonlyArray interface only exposes the non-mutating functions of the array and conceals its mutating functions.
Therefore, to extend the ReadonlyArray interface, you must:

Extend the underlying Array class with your functions.
Expose these functions by extending the ReadonlyArray interface.
Create an instance of the extended array and type it as your new interface.

So, try something like this:
// 1. extend the Array class
class RowVector<ElementType> extends Array<ElementType> implements ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> {
    rowVectorFunction() : ElementType {
        return this[0]
    }
}

// 2. expose that in the extended read-only interface
interface ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> extends ReadonlyArray<ElementType> {
    rowVectorFunction(): ElementType
}

// 3. create an instance typed as extended interface
function createReadonlyRowVector<ElementType>(items: ElementType[]): ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> {
    const rv = new RowVector(...items)
    return rv
}

const rorv = createReadonlyRowVector([1, 2 ,3])
rorv.rowVectorFunction()
rorv.push(4) // error

Playground link

Why class RowVector<ElementType> extends Array<ElementType> instead of class RowVector<ElementType> extends ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType>?

@VLAZ Because a class cannot extend an interface

@Bergi sorry, I meant class RowVector<ElementType> implements ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> for the second one

@VLAZ I added an explanation to the answer.

@ShalomPeles. Thank you for the answer. I have analyzed your solution. I am sorry, but unfortunately it has the big defect called "double management"  RowVector and ReadonlyRowVector does not know about each other while we need RowVector implements ReadonlyRowVector plus the methods of the mutable collection. Contrary to it, if we'll declare some methods at ReadonlyRowVector, TypeScript will NOT complain about these method has not been implemented at RowVector. Because of this, we are forced to manage it manually which makes the mistake occurrence easier.

You're correct. I added implements ReadonlyRowVector<ElementType> to the class RowVector. So now the TS compiler complains about changes in the interface. (even without that, if the class doesn't implement the interface correctly, TS will complain in the createReadonlyRowVector function, since it returns a RowVector class as ReadonlyRowVector.)

Thank you very must for correction. I'll repost once check it and decide the final solution for my case.

Just checked your solution as I promised. Works perfect! Thank you for the solution. Accepted & upvoted your answer.
